# Reshape data from long to semi-wide in R

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have data in which each participant made 3 judgments on each of 9 objects (27 judgments).  The 9 objects varied in a 3x3 design (within subjects) so there are 2 factors.

I'm starting with ID + 27 data columns, and I need to have

- ID
- 2 factor columns: Performance, Situation
- 3 value columns: Success, ProbAdmit, Admit

I have read the manuals on reshape() and melt() and cast() but haven't yet been able to figure out what I need to do to make it happen.  Here is my current progress from which you can see my actual data.

```
scsc3 <- read.csv("http://swift.cbdr.cmu.edu/data/SCSC3-2006-10-10.csv")
library(reshape)
scsc3.long <- melt(scsc3,id="Participant")
scsc3.long <- cbind(scsc3.long,colsplit(scsc3.long$variable,split="[.]",names=c("Item","Candidate","Performance","Situation")))
scsc3.long$variable <- NULL
scsc3.long$Candidate <- NULL
```

The above code leaves me with this:

```
Participant  value  Item      Performance  Situation
4001         5.0    Success   GL           IL
4001         60     ProbAdmit GL           IL
4001         1      Admit     GL           IL
4002         ....
```

What I need is a dataframe like this

```
Participant Performance  Situation SuccessValue ProbAdmitValue AdmitValue
4001        GL           IL        5.0          60             1
...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
require(reshape2)
> dcast(scsc3.long, 
        Participant + Performance + Situation ~ Item, 
        value_var = 'value' )

  Participant Performance Situation Admit ProbAdmit Success
1        4001          GH        IH     1       100       7
2        4001          GH        IL     1        50       5
3        4001          GH        IM     1        60       5
4        4001          GL        IH     0        40       3
5        4001          GL        IL     0         0       2
6        4001          GL        IM     0        40       4
...
```

One way to think of what `dcast` is doing is: "cast" the data-frame into a wide format
where the rows are combinations of `Participant + Performance + Situation` and the
columns are the different possible values of `Item`, i.e. `Admit, ProbAdmit, Success`.
The `value_var = 'value'` indicates that the entries of the `value` column should be displayed, for each "Row-Column" combination.

Comment: excellent!  thank you! I hadn't found reshape2 or dcast yet, but really, the formula was what I really needed.  now that you did it, it looks so obvious of course.  thanks!